# How i can reset keyboard to their original defaults in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard

I know this question asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/24609/how-do-you-reset-windows-keyboard-drivers-to-their-original-defaults), and I have tried the [solution](https://superuser.com/a/33197/924370)
but it doesn't work with my issue

my problem is when I'm trying to press on any key

the key appears with a  number and another character 
 for example : 
when I trying to press

- a = "a1" + open a new tab in browser
- t = "bt5"
- e = "e3"
- o = "o9"
- Enter = "="
- @ = " ¬" "
- 5 = "785"

etc...

It's very annoying, this post took with me 15 minutes to write it

How to get rid of this problem?

**Notes:**

1. Some keys don't work.
2. I am sure there is no was any technical failure, the problem occurred after a sudden the power outage and restarting the laptop.

Comment: Have you tried another (external USB) keyboard?

Comment: I don't have another (external USB) keyboard

Comment: You could borrow one ...

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply
, Currently, I can not
I am using now 
on-screen keyboard win10

Comment: If the on screen keyboard works then you physical keyboard is broken. Go visit a repair shop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having another keyboard to test with, and only seeing that the on-screen keyboard functions correctly, the best assumption at this point is that the problem is with your keyboard, which needs to be repaired or replaced.